# How to config .Net application server?

Tags: java, c#, .net

In java, we have JBoss, Tomcat, etc.

and We can config those application server to better fit our application,

In .Net, is there any need to config application server/windows server to do this same thing?

If not, then how to config the environment that our application to run ? the windows registry?

Comment: IIS is the most used server for .Net applications and offers a host of configurable options. If you can be more specific with the options you want configured, someone will be able to help you I am sure :)

Answer (score 0):

If your are thinking of a windows service:

Create a windows service with an [installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddhy0byf(v=vs.110).aspx) and use [SC](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490995.aspx) to install it. Simply modify the **app.config** file or use the **built in editor in visual studio**, for your configuration needs. You can debug a service like an application, but if you want ot install it:

SC install:

```
sc create YourService binPath= "C:\Program Files\..\your.exe" DisplayName= "YourService"
```

Note the space after binPath= must be there, silly bug...

[Event Viewer is your friend tracing errors such as startup etc....](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-information-event-logs-event-viewer#1TC=windows-7)

If you need to do changes after build (IE different servers) you may change the .exe.config file.

Hope it helps some,

Cheers Stian